# Is there a CSS animation for a floating div that wraps on window resize?

Tags: css, css-float, css-animations

If I have a series of divs all with `float: left` and I resize the browser so they wrap, can I animate their transition to their new location using only CSS animations (no JavaScript)?

Comment: You want to show the divs moving from the end of the line to the beginning of the next line if the user makes the window narrower?

Comment: @MrLister, yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using JavaScript that's most likely a no...

CSS transitions and animations rely on the elements' CSS properties changing. The line wrap behavior you're seeing when the window is resized doesn't change the elements' properties, so you won't have anywhere to add a transition.

Even with JavaScript I doubt creating the effect you're after would be trivial, you may want to check out a plugin like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try use transistions, but I think that in your example it's not possible without JS.

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
```

Comment: I could change the CSS class name via JavaScript if that helps.